# How do I add white-space:normal in this jQuery Mobile grid button text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Here is my jQuery Mobile Grid buttons code:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b my-breakpoint">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/business.png" height="45"><br>Business</button></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/digital_center.png" height="45"><br>Digital Center</button></div> 
  <div class="ui-block-c"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/employment.png" height="45"><br>Employment</button></div>     
</div>
```

Now I want to add `white-space:normal` for wrapping the button text. How and where do I add `white-space:normal` for the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a CSS rule:

```
button {  
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

However the button heights will no longer be equal...